# React handleChange(evt) best practice?

Tags: reactjs

i wanna know if is it good practice to do the following?
i set the state for checkbox, because of the const value conditional
thanks in advance....

```
handleChange(evt) {
    const value = evt.target.type === "checkbox" ? evt.target.checked : evt.target.value;
    this.setState({
      [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value,
    })
    this.setState({
      [evt.target.name]: value
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this function looks good. However, you have used `this.setState` twice so we can optimize this function to

```
handleChange(evt) {
    const value = evt.target.type === "checkbox" ? evt.target.checked : evt.target.value;
    this.setState({
      [evt.target.name]: value
    });
  }
```